# Qt Android Service : How to keep service running when screen is turned off + USB cable not connected?

Tags: android, qt, android-service, qtandroidextras, android-powermanager

Why doesn't the service work all the time in the background when the screen is off + USB not connected?

Using Qt, I created a test android service that uses QTimer to issues Push-notifications every 5-seconds. I did this to monitor whether the service will be always running in the background.

However, after turning the screen off, I get the notifications for around 30 seconds(total:5 or 6), then I get nothing for like 2-3 minutes. Then I get one notification after. Then I get nothing again.

I tried all of the following with no solution:

```
*return START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY;
*return START_STICKY;
```

*Using Power Manager:

```
powerManager = (PowerManager)m_instance.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakeLock");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Btw, the service is not killed, as once i turn Back-On the screen, it resumes.

Why doesn't the service work all the time in the background when the screen is off + USB not connected?

Comment: Same problem. I brick my brain. Do you find solution?

Comment: Yes, what is causing that is a limitation added by Google starting API 23 called "Doze mode". Starting Oreo there are even more limitations on services. So, keeping a service always running is no longer an option unless you use a foreground service.